# Using SIN and COS functions to create a gauge chart “needle” in Excel

Tags: trigonometry

I have a chart built in Excel that uses SIN and COS functions to plot two points in a scatterplot, which are then overlaid onto half a donut chart to create a "gauge & needle" effect, like this:

[image]

The X-value for the needle is calculated using the following function: =SIN(((((B1+C1)*180/C1)+90))*PI()/180)

And the Y-Value for the needle is calculated using the following: =COS(((((B1+C1)*180/C1)+90))*PI()/180)

Where B1 is the current value (where the needle should be "pointing") and C1 is the maximum value.

Can anyone explain to me in layman's terms exactly how these functions are working to create the correct needle position?

Thanks!
-Chris

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a right triangle with the needle as the hypotenuse and the other two sides horizontal and vertical (so that the right angle is between those two sides). The lengths of those sides are the $X$- and $Y$-values, respectively, of the needle’s position. The sine of an acute angle of a right triangle is the ratio of the opposite side to the hypotenuse, while the cosine is the ratio of the adjacent side to the hypotenuse. So, to get the $X$-value for the needle’s position, you multiply the cosine of the angle that the needle makes with the horizontal by the needle’s length, and similarly for the $Y$-value. Multiplying by $\frac\pi{180}$ in those formulas just converts the angle from degrees to radians, which is what Excel’s sine and cosine functions expect as inputs.